# How to zoom in on a specific range of values for a categorical variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, discrete

I just want to zoom in on the x-axis between the values `ford` and `nissan` in the `mpg` dataframe.

Package used: `tidyverse`

But I am getting the following error when using the `coord_cartesian()` function:

```
   p<-ggplot(mpg,aes(x=manufacturer,y=class))

   p+geom_point()+    +         coord_cartesian(xlim = c('ford','nissan'))
```

> Error in `+coord_cartesian(xlim = c("ford", "nissan"))` :  invalid argument to unary operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function for contextual zoom from `ggforce` package (`facet_zoom`) to achieve this:

```r
# loading needed libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

# selecting variables to display
names <- as.vector(unique(mpg$manufacturer))
selected.names <- names[4:11]

# zooming in on the axes
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = manufacturer, y = class)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  facet_zoom(x = manufacturer %in% selected.names)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: but this just zooms in on ford and nissan
I want to zoom in from ford to nissan including all the values in between.

Comment: @Steveaustin Updated the answer.

Comment: Example no workie for me: 
Error: facet_zoom doesn't support zooming in discrete scales

Comment: And the ggforce authors say it is just not possible
https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/issues/99#issuecomment-468386207