# Zoom in on categorical plot with facet_zoom?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

When I attempt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51120227):

```
# loading needed libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

# selecting variables to display
names <- as.vector(unique(mpg$manufacturer))
selected.names <- names[4:11]

# zooming in on the axes
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = manufacturer, y = class)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  facet_zoom(x = manufacturer %in% selected.names)
```

I don't get a zoomed in plot, but instead

> Error: facet_zoom doesn't support zooming in discrete scales

(I have a more detailed real example, but this serves well as an MRE)

#### Question

How can the categorical data be zoomed in on?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to zoom in on categorical data with `scale_x_discrete`, or just `xlim`. Coord_cartesian appears to expect a numeric / mathematical value, which works great for continuous data.

Here's a very basic example:

```
# basic mtcars data plot with car names on x and mpg on y, size = horsepower
library (ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = rownames(mtcars), y = mpg, size = hp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth() +
# to 'zoom in' to see only these two cars
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Datsun 710", "Dodge Challenger")) 
# OR xlim(c("Datsun 710", "Dodge Challenger"))
```

Comment: This code does the 'trick' in that the other points are eliminated from the plot, but it doesn't answer the OP's requirement for using `geforce::facet_zoom()`, which provides additional aesthetics around a zoomed facet.